# How to add Values to Add to cart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have an Add to cart Partial View that I need to add selected items Prices to calculate the total price.
What I want to do is ,when I click on add to cart the AddtoCart partial view update itself with new selected items prices.

Add to cart Partial View

```
@model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel

<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
Added to Cart<br />
Total: 0 @Model.SumVM.ToString()
```

I have a table of Products that contains product details(id,price,details,image)

Product Partial View

```
    @model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel

    foreach (Product item in Model.ProductsV)
    {

            <tr>
                <td scope="row"><img src="@Url.Content(@item.ProductImage)" 
             width="150" height="200" /></td>
                <td>
                    @item.ProductName
                    <br />Price : @item.ProductPrice $<br /> 
          @item.ProductDetails
                 </td>
                <td><button  type="button" class="btn-outline-primary">Add 
         to cart </button></td>
            </tr>
    }
```

AddtoCart Method

```
    public ActionResult AddtoCart(int sum)
    {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {
            SumVM = SumVM + sum
        };

        return View(viewModel);
```

I tried to change the add to cart button into something like that :

```
  <button  type="submit" value="@item.ProductPrice" class="btn-outline- 
  success" name="sum"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddtoCart", "Home")'" >Add 
   To cart </button>
```

but it's not working due to a null reference of the "sum" variable.

Comment: You didn't send the `sum` as a needed parameter to the `AddtoCart` method. You need to specify it in your `Url.Action`. Something like this: `Url.Action("AddtoCart", "Home", new { sum = sumValue });`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Am I right thinking you're wanting to 'add a product to the cart' and display a current total cost for the items within the cart?

Your 'add to cart button' currently submits the page to the controller (server) but doesn't have a 'value' to pass as `sum`.

I'm also taking on board the fact you haven't got a 'cart' in your code and only show the running total. How you store *what* is in the cart is your call with regard to that...My solution is based on the info you have given.

I would have the following (as a basic example) flow:

- products displayed on a page w/ 'add to cart' button on each
- clicking 'add to cart' sends the product price to the controller
- `[HttpPost]` for the controller action accepts a product price and adds the price to the current total in your model
- returns the view with the new total.

I'm assuming the 'products' are wrapped in a `<form method='post' ...>` tag.

```
@model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel
foreach (Product item in Model.ProductsV)
{
        <tr>
            <td scope="row"><img src="@Url.Content(@item.ProductImage)" 
         width="150" height="200" /></td>
            <td>
                @item.ProductName
                <br />Price : @item.ProductPrice $<br /> 
      @item.ProductDetails
             </td>
            <td><button value="150" name="sum"  type="button" class="btn-outline-primary">Add 
     to cart </button></td>
        </tr>
}
```

(Note the added `value` and `name` attributes)

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddtoCart(int sum)
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        SumVM = SumVM + sum
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

There is a lot more needed for a true shopping cart solution but this should solve your immediate issue. You will need the cart to store the product ID of items added, potentially deal with > 1 quantity of items for a start off.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll be working on it ,and will keep you updated if it will work.